# How to supplement Omega-3 fatty acids on vegan diet

Tags: nutrition, nutritional-deficiency

I started a mostly-vegan diet a couple of years ago, and I'm noticing that minor ligament injuries suddenly began taking a very long time to heal, if they are healing at all. I thought perhaps an omega-3 fatty acid deficiency might be the problem.

I'm trying to balance a proper level of omega-3 fatty acids to help improve healing of my lingering ligament injuries but also want to avoid [anti-blood clotting effects that are associated with high omega-3 fatty acid intake](https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/01.ATV.0000137119.28893.0b). At the risk of stating what is perhaps obvious, I don't want to bleed excessively from an accidental cut.

I also read about [ALA to EPA and DHA omega-3 conversion](https://veganhealth.org/omega-3s/omega-3s-part-1/), [daily needs of omega-3 fats](https://veganhealth.org/daily-needs/#Omega-3-Fats), and that high [omega-6 fatty acid linoleic acid intake can interfere with this conversion](https://veganhealth.org/omega-3s/omega-3s-part-1/#improving). I have a high intake of corn grits and peanut butter (which I have seen listed as high omega-6 foods), and it's going to be a significant adjustment if I need to change that.

[Daily needs](https://veganhealth.org/daily-needs/#Omega-3-Fats) recommends

> 1,600 mg / day of ALA

and

> There isn’t enough evidence to determine whether vegans should
> supplement their diets with omega-3s beyond the DRIs. At this time,
> it’s prudent to take one of these additional steps:
>
> ```
> Consume an additional 2,000 mg of ALA per day using the foods in the table above, or
> Take a supplement of 200-300 mg of DHA per day.
> ```
>
> Your DHA supplement can contain EPA, but it’s not necessary if you’re
> meeting the DRI for ALA

**The tools I am looking at to improving my healing ability are**:

1. Increasing ALA intake by eating a lot of chia seeds
2. Taking DHA pills that are made from algal oil
3. Decreasing omega-6 intake

**Background**

I'm male, 40 years old, 180 cm tall, 75 kg weight

**Questions**:

1. How much ALA would I need daily in order to offset eating 1/2 cup dry corn grits and 1/2 cup peanut butter per day? Or is that even feasible?
2. Is just supplementing with DHA pills sufficient, or do I need to get more ALA also?
3. If I need to decrease my omega-6 intake, how much would I need to decrease it?